# How get the gradient background in website which fills the whole page

Tags: html, css, background-image, gradient

i want to have the gradient as background image like this

[image]

how can i achieve that

EDIT:
I want to stretch down to bottom , but if i repeat it then i see the top bar gain , i want that dark portion remain at bottom and central part expands

Comment: What problem are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to stretch down to bottom , but if i repeat it then i see the top bar gain , i want that dark portion remain at bottom and central part expands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **really-really** need to achieve this with background image, [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/YaKkn/).
Of course it doesn't work everywhere — you need JS polyfill to make browser that don't support `background-size` property happy. I would recommend [jQuery Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/) for this.

But, what you really want to do (I hope so, at least) is to make it as flexible as possible and thus, you should take a look at [this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-gradients) or [this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient) CSS gradients tutorial instead of the image. And, of course, you can use one of the CSS gradients generator like:

- http://gradients.glrzad.com/
- http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
- http://css3please.com/. This one is useful for CSS3 in general.

Comment: thanks splitter , i like that but the quality of background image is showing very bad , how can i increase the quality

Comment: if the quality of the image is not good, this might mean you are on WindowsXP and using IE7 or IE6. To workaround the issue with that combination, you might need to take a look at MSIE's proprietary AlphaImageLoader behavior.

Comment: I am using window7 , i think i need to create the new high resolution image for that. Can i get some from web

Answer (score 5):

http://gradients.glrzad.com/

OR

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using a div or other element at the top of the page to give you the 'bar' and use a gradient background image, attached to the body in your css, aligned to the bottom and repeated.

```
body{
background:url(yoururl.png) repeat-x bottom;
}
```

For the 'bar', use the following CSS for the same style effect...

```
.topbar{
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
height:30px; /* or whatever height you want */
}
```

Apply your colours and borders to the bar however you see fit.